# LocalDB with linked table to SQL Server error 7412 switching from non-admin to admin privileges

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2019

We are experiencing a strange issue using a localDB with linked tables to an SQL Server instance using SQL 2019. We see the issue in our own software but can also reproduce it using SQLSMS.

The steps to reproduce the issue are as follows.

- Reboot the computer
- Open our application without administrative privileges using a localDB with linked tables to SQL server instance, the application work perfectly
- Close the application
- Open SQLSMS without administrative privileges and execute a query on the linked tables and it executes perfectly
- Restart the application with administrative privileges and get a number of SQL errors, starting with error# 7412
- Open SQLSMS with administrative privileges and execute a query on the linked tables and SQLMS gives errors as well

In summary, if we first launch the application without admin privileges, we cannot re-open the application with admin privileges without getting SQL errors. The linked tables do not like that the application privileges have changed from non-admin to admin.

If after a reboot we first run the application with admin privileges we can successfully re-run the application with or without admin privileges without any issue.

There seems to be some low level connection between the localDB and the linked SQL database that once established does not like a change of privilege from non-administrative to administrative.

Strangely we can delete the reference to the linked database in SQLMS and create a new linked linked reference and it does not fix the issue.

Using sp_dropserver and sp_addlinkedserver in our application to drop the linked table and re-reference it does not fix the issue either.

The only fix we have found without a reboot is to delete the SQL Service and wait at least 5 minutes. After this wait, it appears the underlying loaclDB linked table connection has been lost and a new one will be created.

We have tried setting a different "Application" name in admin vs non-admin mode to use pooling to hopefully get a completely refreshed connection but this does not seem to affect the low level link between the localDB and the SQL server instance.

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=(localdb)\MylocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;user id=Test_User;password=;Initial Catalog=C:\ProgramData\Test Database\local.mdf;Application Name=Test-Admin; Pooling=true;

Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=(localdb)\MylocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;user id=Test_User;password=;Initial Catalog=C:\ProgramData\Test Database\local.mdf;Application Name=Test-NonAdmin; Pooling=true;
```

We suspect that the connection string is not the issue and that there is some underlying quirk in SQL in the link between localDB and SQL Server. Hopefully someone knows of a way to reset things programmatically so our users are unaware of this strange complication.

The linked server is established with the following parameters (SQL syntax removed)

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'MyServer', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'MyServer',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'Test_User',@rmtpassword='########'
@optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
@optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
@optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
@optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
@optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
@optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
@optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
@optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
@optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
@optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
@optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
@optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
@optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
```

Comment: What's your full Linked Server config

Comment: Updated the original question with the linked server parameters